# How to test if user can display his profile?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I've got a model UserProfile.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)


    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs): #Funckja, ktora tworzy profile użytkownika
        user = kwargs["instance"]
        if kwargs["created"]:
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
            user_profile.save()
    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And his view:

```
def user_details(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    userprofile = user.user
    return render(request, 'user_details.html', {'userprofile': userprofile})
```

The problem is I want to test if user can display his profile by clicking on:

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts:user_details' pk=user.pk %}">Your profile</a>
```

I can not figure out how to do it. I tried to do this way:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from accounts.models import *
from django.test import Client


class UserDetailsView(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.client = Client()
        cls.user = User.objects.create(username="Test")
        owner = cls.user
        cls.user.save()

    def test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
        response = self.client.get('accounts/{}').format(owner)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But it's not working.

The full code is here: https://github.com/Incybro/DjangoShop

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import *
from django.test import Client


class UserDetailsView(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.client = Client()
        cls.user = User.objects.create(username="Test")
        # owner needs to be a class or instance attribute to access it otherwhere
        cls.owner = cls.user
        cls.user.save()

    def test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
        # you formated the response of get instead of the url string
        response = self.client.get('accounts/{}'.format(self.owner))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```